# calculate image position by image count

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

There is a circle and some object around it.the objects number may vary from **1 to n** (dynamic).

**How can i place all this objects around the circle automatically ??**

Tnx in advance.

Comment: The images in your examples aren't showing

Comment: locate the center of the globe, translate the distance to the center (radius) and rotate using 360°/nrOfImages and repeat for all images? My problem with your question would be that you show no effort in what you have tried so far (except asking the question?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a way of doing it. I've added comments in the code to explain the steps. I've taken the liberty to use just colored divs instead of images, but the effect is the same.

```js
// Editor to change the number of persons dynamically
var nr = document.getElementById('nr');
nr.addEventListener('keyup', function(){updatePersons();});

// The globe
var globe = document.getElementById('globe');

// A function to reinitialize the persons
function updatePersons() {
  var personCount = parseInt(nr.value);
  
  globe.innerHTML = ''; // A bit dirty way to remove all previous peeps
  
  // Just add them in a loop, and apply a transformation.
  for (var i = 0; i < personCount; i++) {
    var person = document.createElement('div');
    person.className = 'mens';
    var rotation = i * (360 / personCount);
    console.log(rotation);
    person.style.transform = 'translate(125px, -100px) rotate(' + rotation + 'deg)';
    globe.appendChild(person);
  }
}

// Initial positioning of persons.
updatePersons();
```

```css
#nr {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;  
}

.corea {
  background-color: blue;
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  position: relative;
}

.mens {
  position: absolute; /* Needed, otherwise they influence each other */
  width: 50px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: red;
  transform-origin: 25px 250px;
  
  /* Transform is set in Javascript */
  x-transform: translate(125px, -100px) rotate(180deg);
}
```

```html
<input id="nr" value="5">
<div id="globe" class="corea">
</div>
```

Comment: It was meant as a joke, but I realize it might seem harsh if you don't know the reference. If so, sorry, buddy.